# MySQL / PHP Degree Symbol

Tags: php, mysql

I have a degree symbol (**°**) stored OK in my database and it's shown OK though *phpMyAdmin* (collation set to `utf8_unicode_ci`).

But in my php code, when I fetch the data, the symbols turns into a "�" char.

If I hardcode the degree symbol in my php OK is shown fine, the problem is only when fetch it from database.

html entities and html header does not work in my case.

Comment: Are you using `UTF8` in your markup? In other words, `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in your `head`?

Comment: I tend to prefer collation `utf8_general_ci` because it *works*. On the other hand, make sure your website is sending out the content-type header correctly (ie, with utf8) as well as the correct meta tag.

Comment: The entire pipeline has to be utf. having a utf table in mysql is of no use if the php<->mysql or php<->browser connection are in (say) iso8859

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have UTF header in html, and also in the DSN connection I have dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXX;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: try to use the HTML encoding: `&deg;`

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by the connection to and from the database using something other than utf8.

Try [mysqli::set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) or [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) if using the older library.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I've found the solution:

In the DNS string I had "charset=UTF-8" but it should be: "charset=utf8"